# Sharepoint 2010 Update Item Lookup tangle

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have an OOB approval workflow using SharePoint Designer 2010. I created a column called "**Approver Notes**" for both the list the workflow is on **(ASW Library**) and the **task list**.

I created a local variable called **Variable:Approver Notes** (string) and in the workflow behavior settings "**Before a task is assigned**" I "**Set Task Field "Approver Notes**" to **Variable:Approver Notes**. The Approver Notes section appears on the task form and the information is then inputted into the task list column exactly as it should be.

But now I want to update the column (**Approver Notes**) in the **ASW Library** to match those in the **task list** for that instance of the workflow. So I went into the workflow and have set up "**Update item in Current Item**" but I cannot figure out the lookup conditions. I have the field set up as "Set this **Field: Approver Notes** (ASW Library)" To this **value "Tasks:Approver Notes**" but the lookups for "**Field Data to Retrieve**" and "**Find the List Item**" are giving me trouble. I think this is where my problem lies. No matter what I do I can't get this to successfully update the cell in **ASW Library** with the information from the corresponding cell in the **Task List**.

[image: Update Item in Current Item]

Comment: Can you try "Current Task:ID" instead of "Current Item:ID"

Comment: You need to find the ID of the task item in The lookup. Now you are using the ID of the item to be approved. Usually when an item is created (e.g. a task item) the resulting task item ID ends up in a variable. Have you looked through your task creation workflow if it has such a variable?

Comment: It seems like I _should_ have a Task ID option but it does not appear as though I do. I have a Client ID, a Content Type ID, GUID, ID, Workflow Item ID and Workflow List ID. These are all under the **Tasks** Data source. I don't have a local variable for an ID either.

Comment: @JanJoukeTjalsma Do you mean in the "Before a task is assigned" area? There was nothing there originally, but I created a local variable called **Variable:Item ID** and set it to **Current Task:ID**. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Well yes, there you have the id of the task item. In you screenshot you are not using this variable it seems. Are you sure that in your lookup used for finding the item to be updated you selected not "current item" in the topmost dropdown but "workflow variables" and then your created variable? Perhaps renaming your variabele will make it easier to verify this.

Comment: @JanJoukeTjalsma I changed the "Find the List Item" from the screenshot to be **Field: ID** and **Value: Variable:Item ID**. I published the workflow & attempted to test it, but once again the information does not transfer from the Task list to my ASW one. Not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry, misread. The id of The parent item should be available as a field in the task item. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your lookup needs to be changed to:

Where **ID** matches **task:workflow item id**

See similar lookup here:
https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/create-a-detailed-custom-task-notification-with-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Comment: So do you mean I need to change **Current Task:ID** from **Variable: Item ID** to **Task:Workflow Item ID**? Or do you mean change it in the **Find the List Item** section of **Lookup for Updating the current item**? From the link you gave I would think you mean the **Find the List Item** section but when I do that it just creates another **Lookup for Integer**. Feels like I'm working in circles.

Comment: I meant the latter, I think I see your problem though. Let me get back to you later.

Comment: Ok thanks. I still haven't been able to figure this out unfortunately.